# Merging two columns in a single pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, merge, multiple-columns

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],'A': [1,2, np.NaN, np.NaN], 'A1': [np.NaN, np.NaN, 3,4]})
```

I'm looking to merge A1 into A (drop A1) that should result into:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],'A': [1,2, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 3,4]})
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can `concat` the two columns:

```
pd.concat([df[['id', 'A']], df[['id', 'A1']].rename(columns={'A1': 'A'})],
          ignore_index=True)
```

Or `melt` and `rename`/`drop`:

```
df.melt('id').rename({'value': 'A'}).drop(columns='variable')
```

output:

```
    id    A
0  0.1  1.0
1  0.2  2.0
2  0.3  NaN
3  0.4  NaN
4  0.1  NaN
5  0.2  NaN
6  0.3  3.0
7  0.4  4.0
```

Comment: Shame that `df.melt('id', value_name='A')` produces a `FutureWarning`...

Comment: @Jon yes indeed, I wish it would only produce a warning if the `value_name` would conflict with `id_vars` columns

Comment: @mozway you could raise a PR to fix this; your suggestion is right

Answer (score 1):

one option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/); the columns have a pattern, they both start with `A`, we can use that to our advantage in the reshaping:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd
df.pivot_longer('id', names_to = 'A', names_pattern=['A'])

    id    A
0  0.1  1.0
1  0.2  2.0
2  0.3  NaN
3  0.4  NaN
4  0.1  NaN
5  0.2  NaN
6  0.3  3.0
7  0.4  4.0
```